# How to integrate the Flickr Api in ios

Tags: iphone, flickr

I want to integrate the flickr api to upload the image through my iphone application to flickr site.
I had downloaded the code [snap&Run](http://code.flickr.com/blog/tag/iphone/)from github. i had integrated the same code in my code.But it is showing me the error while navigating back to the application from safari browser.
The error is :-Cannot open page
Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer this link `https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr` of the well known `ObjectiveFlickr` repository. I think it's much lighter and simpler:

- it relies on `AFNetworking`, which is the industry standard
- it has only 4 classes and a good tutorial
- the coding style is more modern

Comment: Thanks For sharing demo source link. But Right now, Demo source is not available there. Can you sent other link or upload there?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr
this will help you !!

Comment: @Deepjyoti Roy I got this and i had used the snap and run code from this.And even i integrated with the code.But i got the error while navigating the application back from the safari browser.can u help me out with the proper step to use this.Thanks a lot

Comment: @Shweta: you gotta handle exceptions. Coz wen u r navigating back from browser the state of your app may have changed, and hence the error!! Proper error handling wil solve your problem !!

Comment: @DeepjyotiRoy thanks for the reply.I had handeld the excetion my taking it in try catch loop.But the main poit is i m not able to  understand the logic snapandrun application of flikr is working after navigating back to application.CAn u please help me how to do it.As it is not as simple like facebook or twitter

Comment: @shweta: sry yaar !! without seeing the code , its little hard to solve !!

Comment: Is there any   another sample code or steps anywhere which could help out of this?please provide if u have any then. Else i post the  code and will give u alink